# Why does adding a positive viewbox min-x, min-y value have a negative translate effect?

Tags: svg

I was just going through **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/BhZjV/335/)** fiddle and the code looks like below:

```
<svg width=200 height=200 viewbox="0 0 225 225" >
    <path d="M220, 220
            A200, 200, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20
            L 20, 220
            Z"
    fill = "lightskyblue">
    </path>
</svg>
```

Now when i play around with the viewbox and change the value to `viewbox="100 100 225 225"` it has the effect of doing something like:

```
transform:translate(-100px, -100px);
```

Well i believe when i specify `100` as the `min-x, min-y`  the values of `viewbox` the effect should have been something like

`transform:translate(100px, 100px);`

But instead the effect is something similar to:

```
transform:translate(-100px, -100px);
```

Why so ? can somebody explain ?

Answer (score 7):

By setting minX and minY to 100, what you are doing is telling the SVG renderer that the top left of your SVG starts at (100,100). And that point should be at the top left of the SVG viewport.

It is the same as if you decided your ruler started at the 10cm mark.  The 12cm mark would appear to be at 2cm instead of 12cm.  In other words 10cm further left (lower).

Have a look at the following sample SVG.  I've marked out an area which we will make set the viewport and viewBox to in a later example.

```html
<svg width="600" height="600">

  <!-- mark the area that will become the viewport -->
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="300" height="200" fill="linen"/>

  <!-- add some other content -->
  <circle cx="120" cy="120" r="20" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="380" cy="270" r="50" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.3"/>

</svg>
```

If we now set the `viewBox` to the cream coloured area and set the viewport (SVG `width` and `height`) correspondingly, you will see what happens.

```html
<svg width="300" height="200" viewBox="100 100 300 200">

  <!-- mark the area that will become the viewport -->
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="300" height="200" fill="linen"/>

  <!-- add some other content -->
  <circle cx="120" cy="120" r="20" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="380" cy="270" r="50" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.3"/>

</svg>
```

You can see that the small red circle which is roughly at 100,100, is now at the top left of the viewport.

Hope this makes it clearer for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer so your saying 100,100 is toward the left and top respectively of 0,0 ?? i am confused should 100, 100 start 100 units from 0 .

Comment: No. (100,100) is down and to the right of (0,0). So if you set your viewBox minX/minY to that value, you are basically telling the renderer to treat that point as the top left.of your picture.  So anything at point (100,100) in your picture gets drawn at the top left.  That makes it look as if everything has been moved up and to the left.

Comment: i am not sure if i am getting closer to the answer or getting myself more confused haha , thanks for trying to explain this concept to me ... you made the following statement `By setting minX and minY to 100, what you are doing is telling the SVG renderer that the top left of your SVG starts at (100,100).` ... when you say starts at(100,100) , is it (100,100) of the viewport or (100,100) of the SVG itself ?

Comment: It is (100,100) in the document coordinate system. So if you had a circle like `<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10"/>` it would be at the top left of the viewport.

Comment: I've added some examples, which will hopefully make things clearer.

Answer (score 6):

1. Imagine you have a sheet of paper with your drawing on it and you overlay a piece of cellulite (or anything transparent) on top.
2. Draw a box on the cellulite and colour in everything outside the box.
3. Move the cellulite to the right.
4. Your drawing (the part you can still see within the cellulite box) appears to have moved to the left.

the viewBox is the cellulite box in this example.