# SVG viewBox: Exact order of translation and scaling

Tags: svg

I am struggling to understand exactly how `min-x` and `min-y` on `viewBox` works, from a technical standpoint (without metaphors).

Two helpful resources I have spent quite a lot of time on:

- [SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11) (official specification) - [7.7 The ‘viewBox’ attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute)
- [Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations (Part 1)](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) - by Sara Soueidan

According to the [SVG 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute):

> The value of the ‘viewBox’ attribute is a list of four numbers
>   , ,  and , separated by whitespace and/or
>   a comma, which specify a rectangle in user space which should be
>   mapped to the bounds of the viewport established by the given element,
>   taking into account attribute ‘preserveAspectRatio’.

And:

> The effect of the ‘viewBox’ attribute is that the user agent
>   automatically supplies the appropriate transformation matrix to map
>   the specified rectangle in user space to the bounds of a designated
>   region (often, the viewport).

And:

> (Note: in some cases the user agent will need to supply a translate
>   transformation in addition to a scale transformation. For example, on
>   an outermost svg element, a translate transformation will be needed if
>   the ‘viewBox’ attributes specifies values other than zero for 
>   or .)

So, my expectation was that defining a viewBox is the same as:

1. First **scaling** the viewbox, so it fills the viewport (assuming same aspect ratio on viewport and viewBox)
2. Then **translating** the viewBox, so it is placed in the viewport according to `min-x` and `min-y` viewBox attributes.

If we look at Sara's two examples, [starting here](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/#viewbox-aspect-ratio), that is not what seems to be happening.

In her first example (`<svg width="800" height="600" viewbox="100 100 200 150">...</svg>`), it looks like:

1. viewBox is placed according to `min-x` / `min-y` in viewport
2. viewBox is **scaled** to same size as viewport
3. viewBox origin is **translated** (moved) to coincide with viewport origin

In her second example however (`<svg width="800" height="600" viewbox="-100 -100 400 300">...</svg>`), it looks like a completely different order:

1. viewBox is **scaled** to same size as viewport
2. viewBox origin is **translated** (moved) somehow in the opposite direction of what viewBox `min-x` `min-y` indicates. It does not coincide with viewport origin - This is different from the first example

Thus, I recognize that I do not fully understand it, because technically it should work the same way in both cases.

Finally, in Sara's examples, I do not understand why the blue coordinate system (user coordinate system) does not itself move, to (100, 100) or (-100, -100) in viewport coordinate system. I thought viewBox was supposed to *translate* and *scale* the user coordinate system?

---

**EDIT:**

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959598/why-does-adding-a-positive-viewbox-min-x-min-y-value-have-a-negative-translate), `min-x` and `min-y` does indeed follow my first set of steps. The viewBox origin is placed in the viewport according to `min-x` and `min-y`, and then translated so its origin is on top of viewport origin. It is then (before or after) scaled to fill viewport.

If that is correct, I have a hard time understanding why the blue user coordinate system in Sara's examples do not always end up with its origin on top of viewport origin. After all, viewBox should modify the user coordinate system.

Comment: The SVG 2 spec has a formal definition of the [equivalent transform of a SVG viewport](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform).

Comment: @ccprog Very interesting, I have studied it for a bit now. Does this mean that the new user coordinate system created by the viewBox is always tightly fitting around any descendant graphic element (assuming graphic's x/y coordinates are 0)?

Comment: No. This algorithm defines two rectangles: one in a infinite canvas (`vb-` values), and one in a renderer/browser (`e-` values) and then draws every grafical content in the canvas in the rendering rectangle such that the _rectangles_ "fit", without any regard to content. The grafical content can be everywhere in the canvas, and can thus end up everywhere in the renderer. Only afterwards everything outside the rendering rectangle is chopped off, everything inside is visible.

Comment: @ccprog Got it. What confuses me here is Sara's blue coordinate system (refer to link in OP). Let's say the viewBox rectangle starts at (-100, -100). When that viewBox rectangle is mapped to the viewport (rendering rectangle), the viewBox rectangle's origin is translated (shifted) to overlap origin of the viewport (rendering rectangle). However, Sara's blue coordinate system does not have space between itself and its content's edges (see viewbox="-100 -100 400 300 example). Thus, our viewBox rectangle does not match her user coordinate system.

Comment: @ccprog Said more simply, setting vb-x/y to (100, 100) does not mean the user coordinate system starts at 100, 100 of the viewport. Instead, when the viewBox rectangle is mapped to the viewport, the user coordinate system just tags along (fixed around its content), ending up wherever after the mapping has finished.

Comment: @ccprog It is starting to dawn on me. I originally thought the viewBox actually defined the user coordinate system. That is not true. The user coordinate system is initially the same as the viewport coordinate system. Then, the viewBox rectangle is introduced on top of the infinite svg canvas, grabs onto whatever is visible inside it and is mapped to the viewport. The user coordinate system just tags along with this mapping, with the viewport coordinate system remaining unaffected. This behavior is why they say that the mapping is equivalent to translate+scale of the user coordinate system.

Comment: That is one way to state it. Regarding Sara's illustration, I would have drawn that orange rectangle to always coincide with the viewBox; in that one example, it doesn't: while vb-x/y are at -100/-100, the rectangle is drawn as 0/0 in the blue coordinate system. That is inconsistent to other illustrations.

Comment: @ccprog 100% agree. That is exactly where my confusion stemmed from. Ahh, so glad I got to the bottom of it. Thank you for terrific insight and help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The offset of the origin of the coordinates `viewBox` on the x-axis** (`min-x=70px`)

`<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="70px, 0, 400px, 400px">`

[image]

In the figure, the origin of user coordinates shifts to the right by `70px`, thereby shifting the entire rectangular viewing area`viewBox (400 x 400px)`to the right along the horizontal axis.

When this happens, the image of the SVG document fragment that is under the `viewBox` is captured and then the viewBox viewing area with the captured fragment is back aligned with the fixed user viewport area with the origin (0,0) in the upper left corner.

The coordinates of the figures are recalculated with the last shift of 70px to the left. Formally it turns out that in the fixed viewing area of the viewport when applying the viewBox the fragment of the SVG document has shifted to the left.

[image]

[**Live Demo**](https://svg-art.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/VB_Left4.svg)

**The offset of the origin of the viewBox along two axes**

`min-x=70px, min-y="70px"`

`<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="70px, 70px, 400px, 400px">`

For clarity, add another red rectangle at the bottom of the picture - `6`

[image]

After transferring the origin to the viewBox, a rectangular `400 × 400 px` SVG document fragment with a width and height count from the origin (70.70) gets into the viewBox.

Image capture occurs. Next, the origin of the viewBox (70,70) is combined with the origin of the viewport (0,0). The coordinates of the figures are recalculated.

[image]

Therefore, red rectangles 5 and 6 become fully visible. Everything that does not fall into this area is cut off. For example, part of the areas of colored circles 1,2 and 4.

[**Live Demo**](https://svg-art.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/VB_Left_Up3.svg)

### Zoom using viewBox

The scale of the SVG document fragment depends on the aspect ratio: `viewport` and`viewBox`

If `viewport` /`viewBox` = `1`, then the scale will be `1`

If `viewport` /`viewBox` different from one, the scale will change in the direction of increase or decrease.

[image]

How does the increase in scale explains the figure below

One pixel `viewBox` stretches to two pixels`viewport`

[image]

[**Live Demo**](https://svg-art.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/VB_M1_1up3.svg)

**Zoom out svg image 1: 2**

`<svg width="400" height="400" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 800 800">`

`viewport / viewBox = 1/2`

[image]

The `viewBox` captures a rectangular fragment `800 x 800 px`, that is, the entire scope of the SVG viewport `400 x 400 px` and an additional `400px` each on the right and bottom of the viewport.

[image]

That is two pixels of the `viewBox` are compressed into one pixel of the `viewport`. Therefore the SVG image is reduced by half.

[**Live Demo**](https://svg-art.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/M1_2up3.svg)

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. Great illustrative explanation. I was actually looking to understand how the viewBox and viewport related to the User Coordinate System and Viewport Coordinate System, and I got to the bottom of it in the discussion with @ccprog in the comments to the OP. In short summary, the User Coordinate system is initially the same as the Viewport Coordinate System. Then, a so called viewBox rectangle is drawn on the SVG canvas, everything outside it is cropped off. Subsequently, the viewBox rectangle is mapped to fit into the viewport rectangle. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 That mapping process results in the User Coordinate System (and thus all visible graphics within it), being translated (moved) and scaled. It is important to keep in mind that the UCS is **not** in fact defined by the viewBox. The UCS remains tied to the graphics within it, as it was originally. It is simply translated and scaled together with the graphics, due to the viewBox mapping. Why is it relevant to understand where the UCS ends up? Because, all other transformations to descendant elements apply to a copy of that UCS, not to the element itself (like in HTML).

Comment: For example, in your first illustration, the UCS actually ends up 70px outside (left side) of the viewport. It still surrounds the graphics as it did before viewBox was applied. One could say that viewBox **modifies** the UCS, but it does **not** define it.

Comment: @Magnus Thanks for asking a question about the most fundamental definition of SVG - engaging the `viewBox` and` viewport`  You are looking for a very deep understanding of this issue.  And it seems to me - you are on the right track. I have prepared some more interesting in my opinion illustrations on the theme `viewBox`. If you do not mind, I will post them in a separate answer.  Since the first answer was very big.

Comment: Go ahead, Alex. Looking forward to it.

Comment: Alexandr, I award you with `SVG` bronze badge for the good work for the community!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

1. In the picture, a gray rectangle is an infinite `SVG canvas`.
2. The green rectangle is the `viewport` that the user sees on its display.
3. The yellow rectangle is the virtual `viewBox` area through which the user looks at the `viewport`.

`viewBox` can move along the coordinate axes of the infinite`svg` canvas as in the positive direction `x-min> 0`; `y-min> 0` and in the negative direction`-x-min`; `-y-min`

**Image processing svg**

- Next comes the capture of a fragment of the SVG canvas, located under
  the viewBox.
- In the next step, the coordinate system of the viewBox is aligned
  with the origin of the coordinate system of the `viewport`. And the
  fragment captured by the `viewBox` image is passed back to the
  `viewport`.
- There is a process of negotiation and options are possible here:

  1. If `min-x = 0` and`min-y = 0`, the width and height of the `viewport`s are equal, respectively, to the width and height of`viewBox`s, then the fragment image does not move or scale.
  2. If the `viewBox` is shifted to the right - `min-x> 0`, the image is shifted to the left. It is clear that by capturing an image to the right of the `viewport` and then combining it with the origin, we thereby shift the image to the left.
  3. If the `viewBox` is shifted below the `viewport`s - `min-y> 0`, the image will go up.

Based on this, there are thoughts that you can implement horizontal and vertical parallax without using `CSS`,`JavaScript`. To do this, simply move the `viewBox` along the SVG canvas, as shown in the figure below. Click the **Start** button.

```html
<svg version="1.1"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="600" height="360" viewBox="0 0 600 360"   >
  <title> Explanation horizontal of parallax viewBox </title>
  <desc> animate the horizontal parallax  by modifying a coordinate of the viewBox </desc>
 <defs>
<g id="canvas-svg" stroke-width="2px"> 
  <g id="canvas-frame1">
   <rect id="v-port1" x="25" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue"   fill="yellowgreen" /> 
 <text id="t-port1" x="75" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">1 </text>
 <text  x="26" y="303" > 0 </text>
 </g>      
  <g id="canvas-frame2">  
  <rect id="v-port2" x="135" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue"  fill="dodgerblue" /> 
  <text id="t-port2" x="185" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">2 </text>
  <text  x="136" y="303" > 1168 </text>
 </g>    
  <g id="canvas-frame3">  
  <rect id="v-port3" x="245" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue"  fill="crimson"  /> 
  <text id="t-port3" x="295" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">3 </text>
  <text  x="246" y="303" > 2336 </text>
  </g>
      <g id="canvas-frame4">  
  <rect id="v-port4" x="355" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue"  fill="orange" /> 
  <text id="t-port4" x="405" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">4 </text>
  <text  x="356" y="303" > 3504 </text>
     </g>
       <g id="canvas-frame5">  
  <rect id="v-port5" x="465" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="1px" fill="yellow" /> 
  <text id="t-port5" x="515" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">5 </text>
  <text  x="466" y="303" > 4672 </text>
       </g>   
 </g>
 
 </defs>
 
  <g id="first-rect">
   <rect  x="25" y="25" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="1px" fill="yellowgreen" /> 
 <text  x="75" y="85" style="font-size: 16pt;">1 </text>
 <text  x="26" y="135" > 0 </text>
 </g>      


  <desc>The SVG canvas is infinite in size. In our example, user a viewport of SVG is in the leftmost position.</desc>  
<use xlink:href ="#canvas-svg" x="0" y="0"> </use>
   
<desc> viewBox is moved along canvas SVG</desc>
 <g id="viewBox1">
 <rect id="v-box" x="25" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="5px" fill="none" />
  <text id="t-port1" x="45" y="225" style="font-size: 16pt; fill:blue;">viewBox </text>   
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="startButton.click+0.5s" end="stopButton.click" dur="20s" from="0 0" to="440 0" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>
 </g> 
 

<desc> The image moves to the left viewport</desc>
<use xlink:href ="#canvas-svg" x="0" y="0">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="startButton.click+0.5s" end="stopButton.click" dur="20s" from="0 -170" to="-440 -170" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
  </use>

<desc> Grey background image of the canvas SVG</desc>
 <g fill="#E5E5E5" stroke="#E5E5E5">
 <rect  x="135" y="0" width="465" height="195"    />   
  <rect  x="0" y="0" width="25" height="195"    />   
  <rect  x="0" y="0" width="135" height="30"    />   
  <rect  x="25" y="135" width="135" height="60" />   
  <rect  x="0" y="315" width="600" height="85"  />   
  <rect  x="0" y="195" width="25" height="120"  />
  <rect  x="575" y="195" width="25" height="120" />
 </g> 
  
  <g stroke-width="1px" stroke-dasharray = "5 5"> 
   <line x1="25" y1="140" x2="25" y2="195" stroke="blue"  />
 <line x1="135" y1="140" x2="135" y2="195" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1px"  />
  </g>  
   <g style="font-size: 16pt; fill:blue;">
 <text  x="45" y="170"  > viewport </text> 
  <text  x="15" y="20" style="font-size: 14pt;"> display the user's  </text>
     <text  x="230" y="90" style="font-size: 40pt; fill:#1E90FF"> canvas SVG </text> 
   </g> 

<g id="startButton">
 <rect  x="520" y="325" rx="8" ry="8" width="60" height="20" fill="#58AE2A" />
 <text  x="550" y="340" font-size="16" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial" text-anchor="middle" 
 fill="white" >Start</text>
</g>
        <g id="stopButton">
   <rect  x="450" y="325" rx="8" ry="8" width="60" height="20" fill="#1E90FF" />
   <text  x="480" y="340" font-size="16" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial" text-anchor="middle" 
   fill="white" >Stop</text>
  </g> 

</svg>
```

Comment: Great Alex. I would be a bit more clear about the Viewport Coordinate System vs the User Coordinate System (aka. Current Coordinate System / coordinate system in user space) just to avoid confusion by future readers. Those two coordinate systems are indeed the only ones. It is on the user coordinate systems that graphics are painted. viewBox and transformations will create a copy of the current coordinate system for the element, and then transform it.

Comment: Otherwise, great explanation. I look forward to diving into your parallax code. I will mark your previous answer as accepted, since all our comments along side it should paint the full picture.

Answer (score 2):

I always mix up *viewBox* and *viewport*. So I'll try to avoid it where possible. And I don't fully understand if you want to setup the transformation matrix for the browser or for SVG. So I'll try to avoid it as well.

The *viewBox* attribute provides information to your browser about the size and the coordinate origin of your SVG graphics. It defines the window into the SVG. Only parts within the window will be visible.

So let's look at an example:

```
<svg width="800" height="600" viewbox="100 100 200 150">
```

This tells the browser that it should draw an SVG graphics that will have the dimension 800px by 600px – in the browser's coordinate system. So within the browser DOM, the SVG component will have that size.

The *viewbox* attribute then tells the browser that the relevant/visible part of the SVG graphics is 200pt by 150pt in size (in the SVG coordinate system). So the browser knows that it will need to apply a scaling of 400% to convert SVG coordinates to browser coordinates.

Furthermore, the *viewbox* attribute tells the browser that the point (100, 100) in the SVG coordinate system will be the top left corner of the visible SVG graphics window. So the browser will translate it accordingly.

Everything with smaller *x* and *y* values in the SVG coordinate system will be clipped, i.e. not visible, as it's outside the windows and outside the space the browser has created for the SVG. Similarly, everything to the right of the SVG coordinate 300 (100 + 200) and below the coordinate 250 (100 + 150) will be outside the window and not visible.

Comment: Thank you, Codo! Sounds like my first set of steps were correct then. It will map the new user coordinate system (UCS) onto the viewport coordinate system (VCS). In other words: 1) UCS is placed within viewport according to min-y/x, then translated (including its containing graphics) so its origin is on top of VCS origin. 2) UCS is then scaled so that it fills entire VCS (assuming identical aspect ratio). Does that sound right?

Comment: I don't really understand UCS and VCS. So I can't tell if it's correct.