# SVG not fitting full width and height of the screen html - not being responsive

Tags: html, css, svg, adaptive-design

```html
   <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5,IE=9" ><![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Untitled Diagram</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
 
 body, html{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .pls{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
</style></head>
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
<div class="pls">
 <svg  width="100%" height="100%"><defs><filter id="dropShadow"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1.7" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset in="blur" dx="3" dy="3" result="offsetBlur"></feOffset><feFlood flood-color="#3D4574" flood-opacity="0.4" result="offsetColor"></feFlood><feComposite in="offsetColor" in2="offsetBlur" operator="in" result="offsetBlur"></feComposite><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offsetBlur"></feBlend></filter></defs><g transformOrigin="0 0" transform="scale(1,1)translate(28,-72)"><g></g><g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 120 L 220 159.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 120 L 220 159.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 168.88 L 215.5 159.88 L 224.5 159.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 168.88 L 215.5 159.88 L 224.5 159.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="160" y="80" width="120" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 100px; margin-left: 161px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Lamp doesn't work</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 250 L 220 279.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 250 L 220 279.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 288.88 L 215.5 279.88 L 224.5 279.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 288.88 L 215.5 279.88 L 224.5 279.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 270px; margin-left: 240px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">Yes</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 270 210 L 309.88 210" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 270 210 L 309.88 210" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 318.88 210 L 309.88 214.5 L 309.88 205.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 318.88 210 L 309.88 214.5 L 309.88 205.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 200px; margin-left: 295px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">No</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 170 L 270 210 L 220 250 L 170 210 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 208px; margin-left: 175px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Lamp<br>plugged in?</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="320" y="190" width="120" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 210px; margin-left: 321px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Plug in lamp</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 370 L 220 419.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 370 L 220 419.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 428.88 L 215.5 419.88 L 224.5 419.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 428.88 L 215.5 419.88 L 224.5 419.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 410px; margin-left: 240px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">No</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 270 330 L 309.88 330" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 270 330 L 309.88 330" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 318.88 330 L 309.88 334.5 L 309.88 325.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 318.88 330 L 309.88 334.5 L 309.88 325.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 320px; margin-left: 295px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">Yes</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 290 L 270 330 L 220 370 L 170 330 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 328px; margin-left: 175px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Bulb<br>burned out?</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="160" y="430" width="120" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 450px; margin-left: 161px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Repair Lamp</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="320" y="310" width="120" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 330px; margin-left: 321px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Replace Bulb</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 231.04 471 L 220 471 L 220 574.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 231.04 471 L 220 471 L 220 574.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 583.88 L 215.5 574.88 L 224.5 574.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 583.88 L 215.5 574.88 L 224.5 574.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 665 L 220 719.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 665 L 220 719.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 728.88 L 215.5 719.88 L 224.5 719.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 728.88 L 215.5 719.88 L 224.5 719.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 698px; margin-left: 240px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">Yes</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 585 L 270 625 L 220 665 L 170 625 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 623px; margin-left: 175px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Lamp<br>plugged in?</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 730 L 270 770 L 220 810 L 170 770 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 768px; margin-left: 175px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Bulb<br>burned out?</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 120 210 L 140 210 L 130 210 L 143.63 210" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 120 210 L 140 210 L 130 210 L 143.63 210" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 148.88 210 L 141.88 213.5 L 143.63 210 L 141.88 206.5 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="-20" y="190" width="140" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 138px; height: 1px; padding-top: 210px; margin-left: -19px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Plug in lamp</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 120 340 L 145 340 L 145 330 L 163.63 330" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 120 340 L 145 340 L 145 330 L 163.63 330" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 168.88 330 L 161.88 333.5 L 163.63 330 L 161.88 326.5 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="20" y="320" width="100" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 98px; height: 1px; padding-top: 340px; margin-left: 21px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Plug in lamp</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 170 L 220 150 L 290 150 L 290 270 L 150 270 L 150 210 L 163.63 210" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 170 L 220 150 L 290 150 L 290 270 L 150 270 L 150 210 L 163.63 210" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 168.88 210 L 161.88 213.5 L 163.63 210 L 161.88 206.5 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g></g><g></g><g></g></g></svg></div>


</body></html>
```

I would like for the diagram to be centred horizontally and fit the full width and height on the screen. Currently the diagram is on the left hand side and I get a vertical scrollbar, if I was to hide the scrollbar then my diagram gets cut off. I have looked through all the questions relating to this with: width and height 100%, having a container and the preserveAspectRatio attribute. However I am unable to find any answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Above is an example diagram of the issue.

Comment: do you have a link showing the error you're getting?? If you have set a manual width inside your container you will end up with a scroll bar

Comment: @ShrewdStyle I am not getting any errors. Yes, it was min height but I removed it and the diagram is still cut off from the bottom

Comment: If you want you SVG to scale without taking ratio into account, you might be best off setting it as a background-image using data uri method and setting background-size to cover on the css. Obviously the containing element should span the entire viewport.

Comment: how are you putting in the diagram, is it a background-image: url()?

I mean is it possible to show your css if you are not getting any errors

Comment: I have added in code snippets and it is svg tags

Comment: Cool, height:100% doesn't work the way you want though; use an absolute or fixed position with top, right, bottom and left set to 0 for starters (on .pls)

Comment: @ravb79 Sadly, that has not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the application responsive, you must add `viewBox`
To place the drawing in the center of the screen, you must add`preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid`

```html
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5,IE=9" ><![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Untitled Diagram</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
 
 body, html{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .pls{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
</style></head>
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
<div class="pls">
 <svg  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" ><defs><filter id="dropShadow"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1.7" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset in="blur" dx="3" dy="3" result="offsetBlur"></feOffset><feFlood flood-color="#3D4574" flood-opacity="0.4" result="offsetColor"></feFlood><feComposite in="offsetColor" in2="offsetBlur" operator="in" result="offsetBlur"></feComposite><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offsetBlur"></feBlend></filter></defs><g transformOrigin="0 0" transform="scale(1,1)translate(28,-72)"><g></g><g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 120 L 220 159.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 120 L 220 159.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 168.88 L 215.5 159.88 L 224.5 159.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 168.88 L 215.5 159.88 L 224.5 159.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="160" y="80" width="120" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 100px; margin-left: 161px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Lamp doesn't work</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 250 L 220 279.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 250 L 220 279.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 288.88 L 215.5 279.88 L 224.5 279.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 288.88 L 215.5 279.88 L 224.5 279.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 270px; margin-left: 240px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">Yes</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 270 210 L 309.88 210" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 270 210 L 309.88 210" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 318.88 210 L 309.88 214.5 L 309.88 205.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 318.88 210 L 309.88 214.5 L 309.88 205.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 200px; margin-left: 295px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">No</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 170 L 270 210 L 220 250 L 170 210 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 208px; margin-left: 175px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Lamp<br>plugged in?</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="320" y="190" width="120" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 210px; margin-left: 321px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Plug in lamp</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 370 L 220 419.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 370 L 220 419.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 428.88 L 215.5 419.88 L 224.5 419.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 428.88 L 215.5 419.88 L 224.5 419.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 410px; margin-left: 240px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">No</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 270 330 L 309.88 330" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 270 330 L 309.88 330" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 318.88 330 L 309.88 334.5 L 309.88 325.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 318.88 330 L 309.88 334.5 L 309.88 325.5 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 320px; margin-left: 295px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">Yes</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 290 L 270 330 L 220 370 L 170 330 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 328px; margin-left: 175px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Bulb<br>burned out?</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="160" y="430" width="120" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 450px; margin-left: 161px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Repair Lamp</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="320" y="310" width="120" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 330px; margin-left: 321px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Replace Bulb</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 231.04 471 L 220 471 L 220 574.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 231.04 471 L 220 471 L 220 574.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 583.88 L 215.5 574.88 L 224.5 574.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 583.88 L 215.5 574.88 L 224.5 574.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 665 L 220 719.88" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 665 L 220 719.88" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 220 728.88 L 215.5 719.88 L 224.5 719.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 728.88 L 215.5 719.88 L 224.5 719.88 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 698px; margin-left: 240px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; ">Yes</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 585 L 270 625 L 220 665 L 170 625 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 623px; margin-left: 175px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Lamp<br>plugged in?</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 730 L 270 770 L 220 810 L 170 770 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 768px; margin-left: 175px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Bulb<br>burned out?</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 120 210 L 140 210 L 130 210 L 143.63 210" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 120 210 L 140 210 L 130 210 L 143.63 210" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 148.88 210 L 141.88 213.5 L 143.63 210 L 141.88 206.5 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="-20" y="190" width="140" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 138px; height: 1px; padding-top: 210px; margin-left: -19px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Plug in lamp</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 120 340 L 145 340 L 145 330 L 163.63 330" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 120 340 L 145 340 L 145 330 L 163.63 330" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 168.88 330 L 161.88 333.5 L 163.63 330 L 161.88 326.5 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><rect x="20" y="320" width="100" height="40" rx="6" ry="6" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"></rect></g><g style=""><g><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 98px; height: 1px; padding-top: 340px; margin-left: 21px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Plug in lamp</div></div></div></foreignObject></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)" style="visibility: visible;"><path d="M 220 170 L 220 150 L 290 150 L 290 270 L 150 270 L 150 210 L 163.63 210" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" visibility="hidden" stroke-width="9"></path><path d="M 220 170 L 220 150 L 290 150 L 290 270 L 150 270 L 150 210 L 163.63 210" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"></path><path d="M 168.88 210 L 161.88 213.5 L 163.63 210 L 161.88 206.5 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"></path></g></g><g></g><g></g></g></svg></div>


</body></html>
 Run code snippet
```

Comment: That works! Can I ask how do you know what values to put in for the viewbox's width and height? Or would I just require to carry on adjusting the viewBox till it fits just right? Thank you so much

Comment: @Gintoki Set the width and height of the viewport as a percentage. viewBox can be changed a little, but I tried to make the drawing fully visible

Comment: @Gintoki Thanks! I can suggest you read my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583873/7394871) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592431/7394871), which will help you understand all the nuances of the interaction between `viewport` and viewBox`

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .pls
      {
        position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;background-size:cover;background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter id='dropShadow'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='1.7' result='blur'%3E%3C/feGaussianBlur%3E%3CfeOffset in='blur' dx='3' dy='3' result='offsetBlur'%3E%3C/feOffset%3E%3CfeFlood flood-color='%233D4574' flood-opacity='0.4' result='offsetColor'%3E%3C/feFlood%3E%3CfeComposite in='offsetColor' in2='offsetBlur' operator='in' result='offsetBlur'%3E%3C/feComposite%3E%3CfeBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='offsetBlur'%3E%3C/feBlend%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg transformOrigin='0 0' transform='scale(1,1)translate(28,-72)'%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 120 L 220 159.88' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 120 L 220 159.88' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 168.88 L 215.5 159.88 L 224.5 159.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 168.88 L 215.5 159.88 L 224.5 159.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Crect x='160' y='80' width='120' height='40' rx='6' ry='6' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 100px; margin-left: 161px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3ELamp doesn't work%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 250 L 220 279.88' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 250 L 220 279.88' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 288.88 L 215.5 279.88 L 224.5 279.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 288.88 L 215.5 279.88 L 224.5 279.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 270px; margin-left: 240px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; '%3EYes%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 270 210 L 309.88 210' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 270 210 L 309.88 210' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 318.88 210 L 309.88 214.5 L 309.88 205.5 Z' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 318.88 210 L 309.88 214.5 L 309.88 205.5 Z' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 200px; margin-left: 295px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; '%3ENo%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 170 L 270 210 L 220 250 L 170 210 Z' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 208px; margin-left: 175px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3ELamp%3Cbr%3Eplugged in%3F%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Crect x='320' y='190' width='120' height='40' rx='6' ry='6' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 210px; margin-left: 321px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3EPlug in lamp%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 370 L 220 419.88' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 370 L 220 419.88' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 428.88 L 215.5 419.88 L 224.5 419.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 428.88 L 215.5 419.88 L 224.5 419.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 410px; margin-left: 240px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; '%3ENo%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 270 330 L 309.88 330' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 270 330 L 309.88 330' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 318.88 330 L 309.88 334.5 L 309.88 325.5 Z' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 318.88 330 L 309.88 334.5 L 309.88 325.5 Z' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 320px; margin-left: 295px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; '%3EYes%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 290 L 270 330 L 220 370 L 170 330 Z' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 328px; margin-left: 175px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3EBulb%3Cbr%3Eburned out%3F%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Crect x='160' y='430' width='120' height='40' rx='6' ry='6' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 450px; margin-left: 161px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3ERepair Lamp%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Crect x='320' y='310' width='120' height='40' rx='6' ry='6' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 118px; height: 1px; padding-top: 330px; margin-left: 321px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3EReplace Bulb%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 231.04 471 L 220 471 L 220 574.88' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 231.04 471 L 220 471 L 220 574.88' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 583.88 L 215.5 574.88 L 224.5 574.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 583.88 L 215.5 574.88 L 224.5 574.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 665 L 220 719.88' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 665 L 220 719.88' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 728.88 L 215.5 719.88 L 224.5 719.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 728.88 L 215.5 719.88 L 224.5 719.88 Z' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 698px; margin-left: 240px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: nowrap; '%3EYes%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 585 L 270 625 L 220 665 L 170 625 Z' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 623px; margin-left: 175px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3ELamp%3Cbr%3Eplugged in%3F%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 730 L 270 770 L 220 810 L 170 770 Z' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 90px; height: 1px; padding-top: 768px; margin-left: 175px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3EBulb%3Cbr%3Eburned out%3F%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 120 210 L 140 210 L 130 210 L 143.63 210' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 120 210 L 140 210 L 130 210 L 143.63 210' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 148.88 210 L 141.88 213.5 L 143.63 210 L 141.88 206.5 Z' fill='%23000000' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Crect x='-20' y='190' width='140' height='40' rx='6' ry='6' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 138px; height: 1px; padding-top: 210px; margin-left: -19px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3EPlug in lamp%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 120 340 L 145 340 L 145 330 L 163.63 330' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 120 340 L 145 340 L 145 330 L 163.63 330' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 168.88 330 L 161.88 333.5 L 163.63 330 L 161.88 326.5 Z' fill='%23000000' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Crect x='20' y='320' width='100' height='40' rx='6' ry='6' fill='%23ffffff' stroke='%23000000' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg style=''%3E%3Cg%3E%3CforeignObject style='overflow: visible; text-align: left;' pointer-events='none' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cdiv style='display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 98px; height: 1px; padding-top: 340px; margin-left: 21px;'%3E%3Cdiv style='box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; '%3E%3Cdiv style='display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: %23000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; '%3EPlug in lamp%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/foreignObject%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0.5,0.5)' style='visibility: visible;'%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 170 L 220 150 L 290 150 L 290 270 L 150 270 L 150 210 L 163.63 210' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke' visibility='hidden' stroke-width='9'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 220 170 L 220 150 L 290 150 L 290 270 L 150 270 L 150 210 L 163.63 210' fill='none' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='stroke'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M 168.88 210 L 161.88 213.5 L 163.63 210 L 161.88 206.5 Z' fill='%23000000' stroke='%23000000' stroke-miterlimit='10' pointer-events='all'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");background-position: center center;background-repeat no-repeat;
    
      }
```

Comment: I do not have a svg file, I am using svg tags