# Scaling an SVG within an HTML viewbox

Tags: html, css, svg, viewbox

I need some help with scaling an SVG in a HTML viewbox.

I am playing around in a HTML template for a website and want to change the standard SVG image of the template to another image. I cannot get the new SVG with the path d=" something, something" to scale correctly.

**I would like the new SVG image to fit correctly into the center of the 91 by 91 viewbox**.

I have looked into the SVG viewbox system online but cannot comprehend how it works. I have some python coding experience but nothing too serious, no HTML experience.

Please help, explanation is below.

The code with the standard SVG image is the following:

```
<div id="section-publications" class="o-container   wow1 fadeIn"  data-contentPosition="4">
<div class="c-section-heading">
  <svg class="c-section-heading__icon svg-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="91" height="91" viewBox="0 0 91 91">
    <rect class="svg-icon__border" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="90" height="90"/>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M441.844,1714.1a3.587,3.587,0,0,1-1.175,2.18,4.8,4.8,0,0,1-2.425,1.12,9.54,9.54,0,0,1-1.5.1,12.291,12.291,0,0,1-1.5,0h-30a5.209,5.209,0,0,1-2.25-.45,3.054,3.054,0,0,1-1.65-1.7,4.191,4.191,0,0,1-.05-2.65,14.023,14.023,0,0,1,.75-1.75l10.95-20.3a2.556,2.556,0,0,0,.25-1.05v-4.65a0.605,0.605,0,0,0-.075-0.35,0.574,0.574,0,0,0-.375-0.15,3.05,3.05,0,0,1-2.175-.97,3.2,3.2,0,0,1-.875-2.28l-0.05-1.65c0.033-.27.067-0.53,0.1-0.8a3.232,3.232,0,0,1,1.125-1.87,3.119,3.119,0,0,1,2.075-.73h16.25a3.213,3.213,0,0,1,2.4.98,3.157,3.157,0,0,1,.9,2.42c0-.5.017-0.12,0.05,1.15a6.137,6.137,0,0,1-.1,1.2,3.257,3.257,0,0,1-1.075,1.8,3.076,3.076,0,0,1-1.925.75,0.574,0.574,0,0,0-.375.15,0.605,0.605,0,0,0-.075.35v4.85a1.7,1.7,0,0,0,.3.8l11.8,20.4a4.6,4.6,0,0,1,.7,3.1h0Zm-2.425.05a4.446,4.446,0,0,0-.675-2.25l-11.2-20.85a1.941,1.941,0,0,1-.25-0.7q0.05-3.645,0-7.2a0.379,0.379,0,0,1,.1-0.32,0.5,0.5,0,0,1,.3-0.08h1.55a1.474,1.474,0,0,0,1.125-.45,1.8,1.8,0,0,0,.475-1.15v-1.65a1.552,1.552,0,0,0-.45-1.15,1.622,1.622,0,0,0-1.2-.45h-16.05a1.722,1.722,0,0,0-1.25.43,1.652,1.652,0,0,0-.45,1.27v1.6a1.755,1.755,0,0,0,.475,1.1,1.474,1.474,0,0,0,1.125.45,9.973,9.973,0,0,0,1.375,0,0.519,0.519,0,0,1,.475.08,0.781,0.781,0,0,1,.1.47q-0.05,3.345,0,6.65a2.09,2.09,0,0,1-.3,1.1l-11.1,20.7a6.541,6.541,0,0,0-.7,1.7,1.652,1.652,0,0,0,1.45,2.2,5.753,5.753,0,0,0,1.3.1h31.25a3.855,3.855,0,0,0,1.5-.25A1.369,1.369,0,0,0,439.419,1714.15Zm-22.2-40.52a1.953,1.953,0,0,1-.575-1.43,2.015,2.015,0,0,1,.575-1.45,1.948,1.948,0,0,1,1.425-.62,1.833,1.833,0,0,1,1.45.6,2.031,2.031,0,0,1,.6,1.47,2.049,2.049,0,0,1-2.05,2.05A2.115,2.115,0,0,1,417.219,1673.63Zm5.05-3.13a1.616,1.616,0,0,1-.525-1.22,1.8,1.8,0,0,1,1.75-1.78,1.734,1.734,0,0,1,1.225.5,1.65,1.65,0,0,1,.525,1.25,1.709,1.709,0,0,1-1.75,1.75A1.734,1.734,0,0,1,422.269,1670.5Zm4.625,23.45,10.3,18.8a3.751,3.751,0,0,1,.45.88,0.2,0.2,0,0,1-.175.27,6.171,6.171,0,0,1-.975.05h-31.1a1.131,1.131,0,0,1-.725-0.12,1.032,1.032,0,0,1,.225-0.68q0.649-1.245,2.6-4.8l4.85-8.85a0.933,0.933,0,0,1,.325-0.4,0.6,0.6,0,0,1,.525.05,19.047,19.047,0,0,0,3.775.75,4.321,4.321,0,0,0,3.775-1.3c0.3-.3.933-0.98,1.9-2.05a13.925,13.925,0,0,1,3.6-2.8,0.712,0.712,0,0,1,.4-0.07,0.463,0.463,0,0,1,.3.27h-0.05Zm-2.35,15.13a1.943,1.943,0,0,0,.2-1.6,2.054,2.054,0,0,0-1.025-1.25,2.132,2.132,0,0,0-2.875.8,2.1,2.1,0,0,0-.175,1.6,2,2,0,0,0,1,1.3,2.05,2.05,0,0,0,1.625.17A2.189,2.189,0,0,0,424.544,1709.08Zm5.025-4.8a2.386,2.386,0,0,0,.2-1.85,2.476,2.476,0,0,0-1.15-1.5,2.325,2.325,0,0,0-1.85-.28,2.352,2.352,0,0,0-1.5,1.18,2.394,2.394,0,0,0-.25,1.9,2.454,2.454,0,0,0,1.175,1.5,2.3,2.3,0,0,0,1.9.22A2.389,2.389,0,0,0,429.569,1704.28Zm-10.725-18.08a3.5,3.5,0,0,1-1.05-2.57,3.465,3.465,0,0,1,1.075-2.58,3.682,3.682,0,0,1,5.15,0,3.622,3.622,0,0,1,0,5.15A3.713,3.713,0,0,1,418.844,1686.2Zm-0.7,7.53a2.643,2.643,0,0,1,1.825-4.53,2.568,2.568,0,0,1,1.85.75,2.477,2.477,0,0,1,.775,1.85,2.62,2.62,0,0,1-.75,1.88,2.493,2.493,0,0,1-1.85.77A2.435,2.435,0,0,1,418.144,1693.73Z" transform="translate(-375.5 -1649.5)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And looks like this:

[image: Working code with SVG]

I would like to change the SVG to something different such as a handshake (or something else at least..). I have a SVG handshake file that looks like this:

[image: handshake example]

When i generate look inside the SVG file i find a path that dictates the coordinates of the handshake image. When i copy and paste the path into the code and remove the transform element i get the following:

```
<svg class="c-section-heading__icon svg-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="91" height="91" viewBox="0 0 91 91" >
    <rect class="svg-icon__border" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="90" height="90"/> 
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M25.267 19.713c-0.628-1.309-2.875-3.127-5.045-4.883-1.211-0.979-2.355-1.904-3.084-2.633-0.183-0.184-0.456-0.243-0.697-0.156-0.449 0.163-0.727 0.288-0.945 0.385-0.333 0.149-0.445 0.2-0.895 0.245-0.199 0.020-0.377 0.127-0.488 0.292-0.943 1.409-1.919 1.289-2.571 1.071-0.208-0.069-0.245-0.159-0.265-0.244-0.14-0.585 0.563-1.948 1.473-2.859 2.167-2.168 3.284-2.711 5.644-1.656 2.677 1.197 5.36 2.135 5.387 2.144 0.351 0.121 0.728-0.063 0.849-0.411 0.12-0.348-0.063-0.728-0.411-0.849-0.027-0.009-2.656-0.928-5.28-2.103-3.057-1.367-4.735-0.467-7.131 1.931-0.912 0.912-2.151 2.757-1.831 4.111 0.137 0.576 0.543 1.003 1.145 1.201 1.511 0.499 2.889 0.021 3.916-1.341 0.424-0.065 0.655-0.161 1.001-0.317 0.125-0.056 0.272-0.121 0.467-0.2 0.763 0.716 1.792 1.549 2.876 2.425 1.96 1.585 4.183 3.383 4.683 4.423 0.247 0.513-0.019 0.848-0.199 1.001-0.264 0.227-0.625 0.299-0.821 0.161-0.216-0.148-0.497-0.157-0.72-0.024-0.224 0.133-0.349 0.385-0.321 0.644 0.045 0.424-0.343 0.667-0.511 0.751-0.427 0.216-0.872 0.179-1.039 0.024-0.187-0.173-0.455-0.224-0.692-0.136-0.237 0.089-0.403 0.308-0.427 0.561-0.040 0.437-0.364 0.857-0.787 1.021-0.204 0.077-0.5 0.124-0.765-0.119-0.165-0.149-0.395-0.207-0.609-0.155-0.217 0.053-0.392 0.211-0.468 0.42-0.025 0.067-0.083 0.227-0.707 0.227-0.444 0-1.243-0.3-1.633-0.559-0.468-0.308-3.403-2.497-5.937-4.62-0.356-0.3-0.972-0.943-1.516-1.511-0.483-0.504-0.924-0.961-1.151-1.153-0.284-0.24-0.704-0.204-0.94 0.079-0.237 0.281-0.203 0.703 0.079 0.94 0.207 0.175 0.607 0.597 1.048 1.057 0.595 0.621 1.209 1.264 1.623 1.611 2.483 2.079 5.467 4.323 6.061 4.713 0.491 0.323 1.548 0.776 2.367 0.776 0.657 0 1.163-0.151 1.513-0.445 0.469 0.183 1.003 0.184 1.516-0.016 0.607-0.235 1.105-0.708 1.388-1.281 0.525 0.112 1.127 0.033 1.673-0.241 0.535-0.269 0.921-0.681 1.113-1.163 0.531 0.028 1.077-0.16 1.529-0.548 0.765-0.655 0.976-1.673 0.533-2.592z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M13.333 8.666h-6c-0.368 0-0.667 0.299-0.667 0.667s0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h6c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667s-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M27.22 18.294c-0.207-0.305-0.62-0.389-0.925-0.181l-1.949 1.309c-0.305 0.205-0.387 0.62-0.181 0.925 0.129 0.191 0.34 0.295 0.555 0.295 0.127 0 0.256-0.036 0.371-0.113l1.949-1.309c0.305-0.205 0.387-0.62 0.181-0.925z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M23.081 21.476c-0.477-0.376-2.612-2.561-3.932-3.937-0.255-0.267-0.677-0.276-0.943-0.020-0.267 0.255-0.275 0.677-0.020 0.943 0.343 0.357 3.365 3.508 4.068 4.063 0.121 0.096 0.268 0.143 0.412 0.143 0.196 0 0.392-0.088 0.525-0.255 0.228-0.288 0.179-0.708-0.111-0.936z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M20.417 22.813c-0.799-0.639-2.805-2.771-3.259-3.264-0.251-0.272-0.671-0.288-0.943-0.040-0.271 0.249-0.289 0.672-0.040 0.943 0.024 0.025 2.419 2.611 3.408 3.403 0.123 0.097 0.271 0.145 0.416 0.145 0.195 0 0.389-0.087 0.521-0.249 0.229-0.288 0.183-0.708-0.104-0.937z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M17.764 24.156c-0.951-0.801-2.896-2.872-3.276-3.279-0.252-0.269-0.675-0.284-0.943-0.032-0.269 0.252-0.283 0.673-0.032 0.943 0.547 0.585 2.408 2.559 3.391 3.388 0.125 0.105 0.277 0.157 0.429 0.157 0.189 0 0.379-0.081 0.511-0.237 0.237-0.283 0.201-0.703-0.080-0.94z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M7.792 7.516c-1.143-1.083-5.712-1.433-7.085-1.515-0.189-0.009-0.364 0.053-0.497 0.18-0.133 0.125-0.209 0.301-0.209 0.485v12c0 0.368 0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h4c0.288 0 0.544-0.185 0.633-0.46 0.097-0.299 2.395-7.349 2.697-10.816 0.017-0.203-0.057-0.403-0.205-0.541zM4.18 18h-2.847v-10.619c2.143 0.169 4.455 0.537 5.295 0.945-0.353 2.92-1.952 8.108-2.448 9.673z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M31.333 7.333c-5.235 0-8.139 1.34-8.26 1.396-0.173 0.081-0.303 0.232-0.356 0.415s-0.027 0.379 0.073 0.541c0.824 1.327 3.404 8.695 3.9 10.492 0.080 0.289 0.343 0.489 0.643 0.489h4c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667v-12c0-0.369-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667zM30.667 19.333h-2.835c-0.632-2.059-2.499-7.427-3.54-9.645 1.017-0.345 3.203-0.939 6.375-1.013v10.659z"></path>
  </svg>
```

The code above looks like this:

[image: New SVG code scale incorrect]

I cannot get the new SVG to scale properly to around the size of the first SVG. With the transform function of the viewbox i can get the image to more or less center in the viewbox but not at the right size.

Please help this newbie out! Thank you so much

Comment: The answers below perfectly explain how viewBox works. In addition, you can see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583873/7394871) on this site with detailed explanations and illustrations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How the viewBox works

It is actually very simple.

In order for the browser to scale your SVG content, to fit the width and height you specify, it needs to know how big that content is.

The way you tell it how big that content is, is via the `viewBox` attribute.  The values in a `viewBox` are:

```
<minimum X> <minimum Y> <width> <height>
```

So say your content was a square from (10,20) to (80,80).  A `viewBox` definition that exactly fitted that square would be:

```
viewBox="10 20 70 60"
```

This is saying that the top left of your content is at 10,20, the width is 70, and the height is 60.

Here's a diagram to show what I mean.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <g transform="translate(50 50) scale(2)">
     >!-- axes -->
     <line x1="0.25" y1="-100" y1="0.25" y2="300" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5"/>
     <line x1="-100" y1="0.25" x2="300" y2="0.25" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5"/>

     <!-- bounds -->
     <line x1="10.25" y1="-100" x2="10.25" y2="300" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-dasharray="3 3"/>
     <line x1="-100" y1="20.25" x2="300" y2="20.25" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-dasharray="3 3"/>
     <line x1="80.25" y1="-100" x2="80.25" y2="300" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-dasharray="3 3"/>
     <line x1="-100" y1="80.25" x2="300" y2="80.25" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-dasharray="3 3"/>

     <!-- rectangle -->
     <rect x="10" y="20" width="70" height="60" fill="rebeccapurple"/>
     
     <!-- labels -->
     <g fill="grey" font-size="6px" font-family="sans-serif">
       <text x="-2" y="-2" text-anchor="end">0,0</text>
       <text x="12" y="-2">10</text>
       <text x="82" y="-2">80</text>
       <text x="-2" y="27" text-anchor="end">20</text>
       <text x="-2" y="87" text-anchor="end">80</text>
       <text x="45" y="87" text-anchor="middle">width = 70</text>
       <text x="82" y="50">height = 60</text>
     </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now that the browser knows the bounds of your SVG content, it can calculate how to scale and position that content so it fits in your viewport.  The viewport just means the rectangle on your page that the SVG is drawn into. You define that using `width` and `height`.

#### Your Handshake SVG

Clearly the `viewBox` for the handshake icon is much too big for the content.  Because of that, it is not being scaled up enough.  We need to find the viewBox that tightly fits that handshake icon shape.

#### But hang on...

But we have a problem.  You have kept the square shape from the previous icon in there. If we scale up the hands shape, the rectangle is going to become too big.
The simplest fix for your problem would just be to scale up and reposition the rest of the content to fit your square:

```css
.svg-icon__border {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="c-section-heading__icon svg-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="91" height="91" viewBox="0 0 91 91" >
        <rect class="svg-icon__border" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="90" height="90"/>
        <g id="test" transform="translate(25,25) scale(1.3)">
            <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M25.267 19.713c-0.628-1.309-2.875-3.127-5.045-4.883-1.211-0.979-2.355-1.904-3.084-2.633-0.183-0.184-0.456-0.243-0.697-0.156-0.449 0.163-0.727 0.288-0.945 0.385-0.333 0.149-0.445 0.2-0.895 0.245-0.199 0.020-0.377 0.127-0.488 0.292-0.943 1.409-1.919 1.289-2.571 1.071-0.208-0.069-0.245-0.159-0.265-0.244-0.14-0.585 0.563-1.948 1.473-2.859 2.167-2.168 3.284-2.711 5.644-1.656 2.677 1.197 5.36 2.135 5.387 2.144 0.351 0.121 0.728-0.063 0.849-0.411 0.12-0.348-0.063-0.728-0.411-0.849-0.027-0.009-2.656-0.928-5.28-2.103-3.057-1.367-4.735-0.467-7.131 1.931-0.912 0.912-2.151 2.757-1.831 4.111 0.137 0.576 0.543 1.003 1.145 1.201 1.511 0.499 2.889 0.021 3.916-1.341 0.424-0.065 0.655-0.161 1.001-0.317 0.125-0.056 0.272-0.121 0.467-0.2 0.763 0.716 1.792 1.549 2.876 2.425 1.96 1.585 4.183 3.383 4.683 4.423 0.247 0.513-0.019 0.848-0.199 1.001-0.264 0.227-0.625 0.299-0.821 0.161-0.216-0.148-0.497-0.157-0.72-0.024-0.224 0.133-0.349 0.385-0.321 0.644 0.045 0.424-0.343 0.667-0.511 0.751-0.427 0.216-0.872 0.179-1.039 0.024-0.187-0.173-0.455-0.224-0.692-0.136-0.237 0.089-0.403 0.308-0.427 0.561-0.040 0.437-0.364 0.857-0.787 1.021-0.204 0.077-0.5 0.124-0.765-0.119-0.165-0.149-0.395-0.207-0.609-0.155-0.217 0.053-0.392 0.211-0.468 0.42-0.025 0.067-0.083 0.227-0.707 0.227-0.444 0-1.243-0.3-1.633-0.559-0.468-0.308-3.403-2.497-5.937-4.62-0.356-0.3-0.972-0.943-1.516-1.511-0.483-0.504-0.924-0.961-1.151-1.153-0.284-0.24-0.704-0.204-0.94 0.079-0.237 0.281-0.203 0.703 0.079 0.94 0.207 0.175 0.607 0.597 1.048 1.057 0.595 0.621 1.209 1.264 1.623 1.611 2.483 2.079 5.467 4.323 6.061 4.713 0.491 0.323 1.548 0.776 2.367 0.776 0.657 0 1.163-0.151 1.513-0.445 0.469 0.183 1.003 0.184 1.516-0.016 0.607-0.235 1.105-0.708 1.388-1.281 0.525 0.112 1.127 0.033 1.673-0.241 0.535-0.269 0.921-0.681 1.113-1.163 0.531 0.028 1.077-0.16 1.529-0.548 0.765-0.655 0.976-1.673 0.533-2.592z"></path>
            <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M13.333 8.666h-6c-0.368 0-0.667 0.299-0.667 0.667s0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h6c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667s-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667z"></path>
            <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M27.22 18.294c-0.207-0.305-0.62-0.389-0.925-0.181l-1.949 1.309c-0.305 0.205-0.387 0.62-0.181 0.925 0.129 0.191 0.34 0.295 0.555 0.295 0.127 0 0.256-0.036 0.371-0.113l1.949-1.309c0.305-0.205 0.387-0.62 0.181-0.925z"></path>
            <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M23.081 21.476c-0.477-0.376-2.612-2.561-3.932-3.937-0.255-0.267-0.677-0.276-0.943-0.020-0.267 0.255-0.275 0.677-0.020 0.943 0.343 0.357 3.365 3.508 4.068 4.063 0.121 0.096 0.268 0.143 0.412 0.143 0.196 0 0.392-0.088 0.525-0.255 0.228-0.288 0.179-0.708-0.111-0.936z"></path>
            <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M20.417 22.813c-0.799-0.639-2.805-2.771-3.259-3.264-0.251-0.272-0.671-0.288-0.943-0.040-0.271 0.249-0.289 0.672-0.040 0.943 0.024 0.025 2.419 2.611 3.408 3.403 0.123 0.097 0.271 0.145 0.416 0.145 0.195 0 0.389-0.087 0.521-0.249 0.229-0.288 0.183-0.708-0.104-0.937z"></path>
            <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M17.764 24.156c-0.951-0.801-2.896-2.872-3.276-3.279-0.252-0.269-0.675-0.284-0.943-0.032-0.269 0.252-0.283 0.673-0.032 0.943 0.547 0.585 2.408 2.559 3.391 3.388 0.125 0.105 0.277 0.157 0.429 0.157 0.189 0 0.379-0.081 0.511-0.237 0.237-0.283 0.201-0.703-0.080-0.94z"></path>
            <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M7.792 7.516c-1.143-1.083-5.712-1.433-7.085-1.515-0.189-0.009-0.364 0.053-0.497 0.18-0.133 0.125-0.209 0.301-0.209 0.485v12c0 0.368 0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h4c0.288 0 0.544-0.185 0.633-0.46 0.097-0.299 2.395-7.349 2.697-10.816 0.017-0.203-0.057-0.403-0.205-0.541zM4.18 18h-2.847v-10.619c2.143 0.169 4.455 0.537 5.295 0.945-0.353 2.92-1.952 8.108-2.448 9.673z"></path>
            <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M31.333 7.333c-5.235 0-8.139 1.34-8.26 1.396-0.173 0.081-0.303 0.232-0.356 0.415s-0.027 0.379 0.073 0.541c0.824 1.327 3.404 8.695 3.9 10.492 0.080 0.289 0.343 0.489 0.643 0.489h4c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667v-12c0-0.369-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667zM30.667 19.333h-2.835c-0.632-2.059-2.499-7.427-3.54-9.645 1.017-0.345 3.203-0.939 6.375-1.013v10.659z"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
```

#### Adjusting the viewBox

Another option would be to get rid of the square, so you don't have to worry about it.  Calculate a more appropriate `viewBox`.  Then you can size and position the icon how you like.  And if you want the square back later, you could add a border style to its parent container.

So how do we work out what the correct `viewBox` should be?  Well, there are a few ways to do that.

- You can do it experimentally by manually changing the values
- You can load it into a vector or SVG editor and use its rulers
- You can use the Javascript method `getBBox()` on your SVG.  The `getBBox()` function returns the bounds of the content.  Those will help inform what the `viewBox` values should be.

If we remove the square from the SVG and use that last method, we get bounding box values of:

```
{
  "x": 0.0009997636079788208,
  "y": 6.000142574310303,
  "width": 31.998998641967773,
  "height": 19.99785614013672
}
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("test-svg").getBBox());
```

```css
.svg-icon__border {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="test-svg" class="c-section-heading__icon svg-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="91" height="91" viewBox="0 0 91 91" >
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M25.267 19.713c-0.628-1.309-2.875-3.127-5.045-4.883-1.211-0.979-2.355-1.904-3.084-2.633-0.183-0.184-0.456-0.243-0.697-0.156-0.449 0.163-0.727 0.288-0.945 0.385-0.333 0.149-0.445 0.2-0.895 0.245-0.199 0.020-0.377 0.127-0.488 0.292-0.943 1.409-1.919 1.289-2.571 1.071-0.208-0.069-0.245-0.159-0.265-0.244-0.14-0.585 0.563-1.948 1.473-2.859 2.167-2.168 3.284-2.711 5.644-1.656 2.677 1.197 5.36 2.135 5.387 2.144 0.351 0.121 0.728-0.063 0.849-0.411 0.12-0.348-0.063-0.728-0.411-0.849-0.027-0.009-2.656-0.928-5.28-2.103-3.057-1.367-4.735-0.467-7.131 1.931-0.912 0.912-2.151 2.757-1.831 4.111 0.137 0.576 0.543 1.003 1.145 1.201 1.511 0.499 2.889 0.021 3.916-1.341 0.424-0.065 0.655-0.161 1.001-0.317 0.125-0.056 0.272-0.121 0.467-0.2 0.763 0.716 1.792 1.549 2.876 2.425 1.96 1.585 4.183 3.383 4.683 4.423 0.247 0.513-0.019 0.848-0.199 1.001-0.264 0.227-0.625 0.299-0.821 0.161-0.216-0.148-0.497-0.157-0.72-0.024-0.224 0.133-0.349 0.385-0.321 0.644 0.045 0.424-0.343 0.667-0.511 0.751-0.427 0.216-0.872 0.179-1.039 0.024-0.187-0.173-0.455-0.224-0.692-0.136-0.237 0.089-0.403 0.308-0.427 0.561-0.040 0.437-0.364 0.857-0.787 1.021-0.204 0.077-0.5 0.124-0.765-0.119-0.165-0.149-0.395-0.207-0.609-0.155-0.217 0.053-0.392 0.211-0.468 0.42-0.025 0.067-0.083 0.227-0.707 0.227-0.444 0-1.243-0.3-1.633-0.559-0.468-0.308-3.403-2.497-5.937-4.62-0.356-0.3-0.972-0.943-1.516-1.511-0.483-0.504-0.924-0.961-1.151-1.153-0.284-0.24-0.704-0.204-0.94 0.079-0.237 0.281-0.203 0.703 0.079 0.94 0.207 0.175 0.607 0.597 1.048 1.057 0.595 0.621 1.209 1.264 1.623 1.611 2.483 2.079 5.467 4.323 6.061 4.713 0.491 0.323 1.548 0.776 2.367 0.776 0.657 0 1.163-0.151 1.513-0.445 0.469 0.183 1.003 0.184 1.516-0.016 0.607-0.235 1.105-0.708 1.388-1.281 0.525 0.112 1.127 0.033 1.673-0.241 0.535-0.269 0.921-0.681 1.113-1.163 0.531 0.028 1.077-0.16 1.529-0.548 0.765-0.655 0.976-1.673 0.533-2.592z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M13.333 8.666h-6c-0.368 0-0.667 0.299-0.667 0.667s0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h6c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667s-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M27.22 18.294c-0.207-0.305-0.62-0.389-0.925-0.181l-1.949 1.309c-0.305 0.205-0.387 0.62-0.181 0.925 0.129 0.191 0.34 0.295 0.555 0.295 0.127 0 0.256-0.036 0.371-0.113l1.949-1.309c0.305-0.205 0.387-0.62 0.181-0.925z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M23.081 21.476c-0.477-0.376-2.612-2.561-3.932-3.937-0.255-0.267-0.677-0.276-0.943-0.020-0.267 0.255-0.275 0.677-0.020 0.943 0.343 0.357 3.365 3.508 4.068 4.063 0.121 0.096 0.268 0.143 0.412 0.143 0.196 0 0.392-0.088 0.525-0.255 0.228-0.288 0.179-0.708-0.111-0.936z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M20.417 22.813c-0.799-0.639-2.805-2.771-3.259-3.264-0.251-0.272-0.671-0.288-0.943-0.040-0.271 0.249-0.289 0.672-0.040 0.943 0.024 0.025 2.419 2.611 3.408 3.403 0.123 0.097 0.271 0.145 0.416 0.145 0.195 0 0.389-0.087 0.521-0.249 0.229-0.288 0.183-0.708-0.104-0.937z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M17.764 24.156c-0.951-0.801-2.896-2.872-3.276-3.279-0.252-0.269-0.675-0.284-0.943-0.032-0.269 0.252-0.283 0.673-0.032 0.943 0.547 0.585 2.408 2.559 3.391 3.388 0.125 0.105 0.277 0.157 0.429 0.157 0.189 0 0.379-0.081 0.511-0.237 0.237-0.283 0.201-0.703-0.080-0.94z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M7.792 7.516c-1.143-1.083-5.712-1.433-7.085-1.515-0.189-0.009-0.364 0.053-0.497 0.18-0.133 0.125-0.209 0.301-0.209 0.485v12c0 0.368 0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h4c0.288 0 0.544-0.185 0.633-0.46 0.097-0.299 2.395-7.349 2.697-10.816 0.017-0.203-0.057-0.403-0.205-0.541zM4.18 18h-2.847v-10.619c2.143 0.169 4.455 0.537 5.295 0.945-0.353 2.92-1.952 8.108-2.448 9.673z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M31.333 7.333c-5.235 0-8.139 1.34-8.26 1.396-0.173 0.081-0.303 0.232-0.356 0.415s-0.027 0.379 0.073 0.541c0.824 1.327 3.404 8.695 3.9 10.492 0.080 0.289 0.343 0.489 0.643 0.489h4c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667v-12c0-0.369-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667zM30.667 19.333h-2.835c-0.632-2.059-2.499-7.427-3.54-9.645 1.017-0.345 3.203-0.939 6.375-1.013v10.659z"></path>
  </svg>
```

From those values we can see that our icon covers from (roughly) 0 to 32 in the X direction, and 6 to 20 in the Y direction.

From that it is fairly obvious that this icon was designed to fit in a 32x32 SVG.  So lets set the `viewBox` to that:

```
viewBox="0 0 32 32"
```

Here's what that looks like, still with `width="91" height="91"`.  I have also added a green border around the SVG, as a replacement for the rectangle that we removed.

```css
svg {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<svg id="test-svg" class="c-section-heading__icon svg-icon" width="91" height="91" viewBox="0 0 32 32" >
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M25.267 19.713c-0.628-1.309-2.875-3.127-5.045-4.883-1.211-0.979-2.355-1.904-3.084-2.633-0.183-0.184-0.456-0.243-0.697-0.156-0.449 0.163-0.727 0.288-0.945 0.385-0.333 0.149-0.445 0.2-0.895 0.245-0.199 0.020-0.377 0.127-0.488 0.292-0.943 1.409-1.919 1.289-2.571 1.071-0.208-0.069-0.245-0.159-0.265-0.244-0.14-0.585 0.563-1.948 1.473-2.859 2.167-2.168 3.284-2.711 5.644-1.656 2.677 1.197 5.36 2.135 5.387 2.144 0.351 0.121 0.728-0.063 0.849-0.411 0.12-0.348-0.063-0.728-0.411-0.849-0.027-0.009-2.656-0.928-5.28-2.103-3.057-1.367-4.735-0.467-7.131 1.931-0.912 0.912-2.151 2.757-1.831 4.111 0.137 0.576 0.543 1.003 1.145 1.201 1.511 0.499 2.889 0.021 3.916-1.341 0.424-0.065 0.655-0.161 1.001-0.317 0.125-0.056 0.272-0.121 0.467-0.2 0.763 0.716 1.792 1.549 2.876 2.425 1.96 1.585 4.183 3.383 4.683 4.423 0.247 0.513-0.019 0.848-0.199 1.001-0.264 0.227-0.625 0.299-0.821 0.161-0.216-0.148-0.497-0.157-0.72-0.024-0.224 0.133-0.349 0.385-0.321 0.644 0.045 0.424-0.343 0.667-0.511 0.751-0.427 0.216-0.872 0.179-1.039 0.024-0.187-0.173-0.455-0.224-0.692-0.136-0.237 0.089-0.403 0.308-0.427 0.561-0.040 0.437-0.364 0.857-0.787 1.021-0.204 0.077-0.5 0.124-0.765-0.119-0.165-0.149-0.395-0.207-0.609-0.155-0.217 0.053-0.392 0.211-0.468 0.42-0.025 0.067-0.083 0.227-0.707 0.227-0.444 0-1.243-0.3-1.633-0.559-0.468-0.308-3.403-2.497-5.937-4.62-0.356-0.3-0.972-0.943-1.516-1.511-0.483-0.504-0.924-0.961-1.151-1.153-0.284-0.24-0.704-0.204-0.94 0.079-0.237 0.281-0.203 0.703 0.079 0.94 0.207 0.175 0.607 0.597 1.048 1.057 0.595 0.621 1.209 1.264 1.623 1.611 2.483 2.079 5.467 4.323 6.061 4.713 0.491 0.323 1.548 0.776 2.367 0.776 0.657 0 1.163-0.151 1.513-0.445 0.469 0.183 1.003 0.184 1.516-0.016 0.607-0.235 1.105-0.708 1.388-1.281 0.525 0.112 1.127 0.033 1.673-0.241 0.535-0.269 0.921-0.681 1.113-1.163 0.531 0.028 1.077-0.16 1.529-0.548 0.765-0.655 0.976-1.673 0.533-2.592z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M13.333 8.666h-6c-0.368 0-0.667 0.299-0.667 0.667s0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h6c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667s-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M27.22 18.294c-0.207-0.305-0.62-0.389-0.925-0.181l-1.949 1.309c-0.305 0.205-0.387 0.62-0.181 0.925 0.129 0.191 0.34 0.295 0.555 0.295 0.127 0 0.256-0.036 0.371-0.113l1.949-1.309c0.305-0.205 0.387-0.62 0.181-0.925z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M23.081 21.476c-0.477-0.376-2.612-2.561-3.932-3.937-0.255-0.267-0.677-0.276-0.943-0.020-0.267 0.255-0.275 0.677-0.020 0.943 0.343 0.357 3.365 3.508 4.068 4.063 0.121 0.096 0.268 0.143 0.412 0.143 0.196 0 0.392-0.088 0.525-0.255 0.228-0.288 0.179-0.708-0.111-0.936z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M20.417 22.813c-0.799-0.639-2.805-2.771-3.259-3.264-0.251-0.272-0.671-0.288-0.943-0.040-0.271 0.249-0.289 0.672-0.040 0.943 0.024 0.025 2.419 2.611 3.408 3.403 0.123 0.097 0.271 0.145 0.416 0.145 0.195 0 0.389-0.087 0.521-0.249 0.229-0.288 0.183-0.708-0.104-0.937z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M17.764 24.156c-0.951-0.801-2.896-2.872-3.276-3.279-0.252-0.269-0.675-0.284-0.943-0.032-0.269 0.252-0.283 0.673-0.032 0.943 0.547 0.585 2.408 2.559 3.391 3.388 0.125 0.105 0.277 0.157 0.429 0.157 0.189 0 0.379-0.081 0.511-0.237 0.237-0.283 0.201-0.703-0.080-0.94z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M7.792 7.516c-1.143-1.083-5.712-1.433-7.085-1.515-0.189-0.009-0.364 0.053-0.497 0.18-0.133 0.125-0.209 0.301-0.209 0.485v12c0 0.368 0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h4c0.288 0 0.544-0.185 0.633-0.46 0.097-0.299 2.395-7.349 2.697-10.816 0.017-0.203-0.057-0.403-0.205-0.541zM4.18 18h-2.847v-10.619c2.143 0.169 4.455 0.537 5.295 0.945-0.353 2.92-1.952 8.108-2.448 9.673z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M31.333 7.333c-5.235 0-8.139 1.34-8.26 1.396-0.173 0.081-0.303 0.232-0.356 0.415s-0.027 0.379 0.073 0.541c0.824 1.327 3.404 8.695 3.9 10.492 0.080 0.289 0.343 0.489 0.643 0.489h4c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667v-12c0-0.369-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667zM30.667 19.333h-2.835c-0.632-2.059-2.499-7.427-3.54-9.645 1.017-0.345 3.203-0.939 6.375-1.013v10.659z"></path>
  </svg>
```

#### Next steps

Now that we have the "correct" `viewBox` you can see that the hands are being scaled up to fill our viewport (the `width` and `height`) area.  But it does mean the padding around the icon, that the original one had, is gone.

To get this padding back, you have a couple of options:

1. Incorporate the padding into the `viewBox`.  You can do this by subtracting an amount from the `<minimum X>` and the `<minimum Y>` values in the `viewBox` and adding extra to the `<width>` and `<height>` values.  For example, if we added a 16 unit padding around our 32x32 shape, the adjusted `viewBox` would be:

   viewBox="-16 -16 64 64"

Demo:

```css
svg {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<svg id="test-svg" class="c-section-heading__icon svg-icon" width="91" height="91" viewBox="-16 -16 64 64" >
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M25.267 19.713c-0.628-1.309-2.875-3.127-5.045-4.883-1.211-0.979-2.355-1.904-3.084-2.633-0.183-0.184-0.456-0.243-0.697-0.156-0.449 0.163-0.727 0.288-0.945 0.385-0.333 0.149-0.445 0.2-0.895 0.245-0.199 0.020-0.377 0.127-0.488 0.292-0.943 1.409-1.919 1.289-2.571 1.071-0.208-0.069-0.245-0.159-0.265-0.244-0.14-0.585 0.563-1.948 1.473-2.859 2.167-2.168 3.284-2.711 5.644-1.656 2.677 1.197 5.36 2.135 5.387 2.144 0.351 0.121 0.728-0.063 0.849-0.411 0.12-0.348-0.063-0.728-0.411-0.849-0.027-0.009-2.656-0.928-5.28-2.103-3.057-1.367-4.735-0.467-7.131 1.931-0.912 0.912-2.151 2.757-1.831 4.111 0.137 0.576 0.543 1.003 1.145 1.201 1.511 0.499 2.889 0.021 3.916-1.341 0.424-0.065 0.655-0.161 1.001-0.317 0.125-0.056 0.272-0.121 0.467-0.2 0.763 0.716 1.792 1.549 2.876 2.425 1.96 1.585 4.183 3.383 4.683 4.423 0.247 0.513-0.019 0.848-0.199 1.001-0.264 0.227-0.625 0.299-0.821 0.161-0.216-0.148-0.497-0.157-0.72-0.024-0.224 0.133-0.349 0.385-0.321 0.644 0.045 0.424-0.343 0.667-0.511 0.751-0.427 0.216-0.872 0.179-1.039 0.024-0.187-0.173-0.455-0.224-0.692-0.136-0.237 0.089-0.403 0.308-0.427 0.561-0.040 0.437-0.364 0.857-0.787 1.021-0.204 0.077-0.5 0.124-0.765-0.119-0.165-0.149-0.395-0.207-0.609-0.155-0.217 0.053-0.392 0.211-0.468 0.42-0.025 0.067-0.083 0.227-0.707 0.227-0.444 0-1.243-0.3-1.633-0.559-0.468-0.308-3.403-2.497-5.937-4.62-0.356-0.3-0.972-0.943-1.516-1.511-0.483-0.504-0.924-0.961-1.151-1.153-0.284-0.24-0.704-0.204-0.94 0.079-0.237 0.281-0.203 0.703 0.079 0.94 0.207 0.175 0.607 0.597 1.048 1.057 0.595 0.621 1.209 1.264 1.623 1.611 2.483 2.079 5.467 4.323 6.061 4.713 0.491 0.323 1.548 0.776 2.367 0.776 0.657 0 1.163-0.151 1.513-0.445 0.469 0.183 1.003 0.184 1.516-0.016 0.607-0.235 1.105-0.708 1.388-1.281 0.525 0.112 1.127 0.033 1.673-0.241 0.535-0.269 0.921-0.681 1.113-1.163 0.531 0.028 1.077-0.16 1.529-0.548 0.765-0.655 0.976-1.673 0.533-2.592z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M13.333 8.666h-6c-0.368 0-0.667 0.299-0.667 0.667s0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h6c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667s-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M27.22 18.294c-0.207-0.305-0.62-0.389-0.925-0.181l-1.949 1.309c-0.305 0.205-0.387 0.62-0.181 0.925 0.129 0.191 0.34 0.295 0.555 0.295 0.127 0 0.256-0.036 0.371-0.113l1.949-1.309c0.305-0.205 0.387-0.62 0.181-0.925z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M23.081 21.476c-0.477-0.376-2.612-2.561-3.932-3.937-0.255-0.267-0.677-0.276-0.943-0.020-0.267 0.255-0.275 0.677-0.020 0.943 0.343 0.357 3.365 3.508 4.068 4.063 0.121 0.096 0.268 0.143 0.412 0.143 0.196 0 0.392-0.088 0.525-0.255 0.228-0.288 0.179-0.708-0.111-0.936z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M20.417 22.813c-0.799-0.639-2.805-2.771-3.259-3.264-0.251-0.272-0.671-0.288-0.943-0.040-0.271 0.249-0.289 0.672-0.040 0.943 0.024 0.025 2.419 2.611 3.408 3.403 0.123 0.097 0.271 0.145 0.416 0.145 0.195 0 0.389-0.087 0.521-0.249 0.229-0.288 0.183-0.708-0.104-0.937z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M17.764 24.156c-0.951-0.801-2.896-2.872-3.276-3.279-0.252-0.269-0.675-0.284-0.943-0.032-0.269 0.252-0.283 0.673-0.032 0.943 0.547 0.585 2.408 2.559 3.391 3.388 0.125 0.105 0.277 0.157 0.429 0.157 0.189 0 0.379-0.081 0.511-0.237 0.237-0.283 0.201-0.703-0.080-0.94z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M7.792 7.516c-1.143-1.083-5.712-1.433-7.085-1.515-0.189-0.009-0.364 0.053-0.497 0.18-0.133 0.125-0.209 0.301-0.209 0.485v12c0 0.368 0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h4c0.288 0 0.544-0.185 0.633-0.46 0.097-0.299 2.395-7.349 2.697-10.816 0.017-0.203-0.057-0.403-0.205-0.541zM4.18 18h-2.847v-10.619c2.143 0.169 4.455 0.537 5.295 0.945-0.353 2.92-1.952 8.108-2.448 9.673z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M31.333 7.333c-5.235 0-8.139 1.34-8.26 1.396-0.173 0.081-0.303 0.232-0.356 0.415s-0.027 0.379 0.073 0.541c0.824 1.327 3.404 8.695 3.9 10.492 0.080 0.289 0.343 0.489 0.643 0.489h4c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667v-12c0-0.369-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667zM30.667 19.333h-2.835c-0.632-2.059-2.499-7.427-3.54-9.645 1.017-0.345 3.203-0.939 6.375-1.013v10.659z"></path>
  </svg>
```

Or you can use CSS styles to size and position your new icon inside a `<div>` container.

Demo:

```css
div.icon-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 23px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

div.icon-container svg {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-container">
  <svg id="test-svg" class="c-section-heading__icon svg-icon" viewBox=" 0 0 32 32" >
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M25.267 19.713c-0.628-1.309-2.875-3.127-5.045-4.883-1.211-0.979-2.355-1.904-3.084-2.633-0.183-0.184-0.456-0.243-0.697-0.156-0.449 0.163-0.727 0.288-0.945 0.385-0.333 0.149-0.445 0.2-0.895 0.245-0.199 0.020-0.377 0.127-0.488 0.292-0.943 1.409-1.919 1.289-2.571 1.071-0.208-0.069-0.245-0.159-0.265-0.244-0.14-0.585 0.563-1.948 1.473-2.859 2.167-2.168 3.284-2.711 5.644-1.656 2.677 1.197 5.36 2.135 5.387 2.144 0.351 0.121 0.728-0.063 0.849-0.411 0.12-0.348-0.063-0.728-0.411-0.849-0.027-0.009-2.656-0.928-5.28-2.103-3.057-1.367-4.735-0.467-7.131 1.931-0.912 0.912-2.151 2.757-1.831 4.111 0.137 0.576 0.543 1.003 1.145 1.201 1.511 0.499 2.889 0.021 3.916-1.341 0.424-0.065 0.655-0.161 1.001-0.317 0.125-0.056 0.272-0.121 0.467-0.2 0.763 0.716 1.792 1.549 2.876 2.425 1.96 1.585 4.183 3.383 4.683 4.423 0.247 0.513-0.019 0.848-0.199 1.001-0.264 0.227-0.625 0.299-0.821 0.161-0.216-0.148-0.497-0.157-0.72-0.024-0.224 0.133-0.349 0.385-0.321 0.644 0.045 0.424-0.343 0.667-0.511 0.751-0.427 0.216-0.872 0.179-1.039 0.024-0.187-0.173-0.455-0.224-0.692-0.136-0.237 0.089-0.403 0.308-0.427 0.561-0.040 0.437-0.364 0.857-0.787 1.021-0.204 0.077-0.5 0.124-0.765-0.119-0.165-0.149-0.395-0.207-0.609-0.155-0.217 0.053-0.392 0.211-0.468 0.42-0.025 0.067-0.083 0.227-0.707 0.227-0.444 0-1.243-0.3-1.633-0.559-0.468-0.308-3.403-2.497-5.937-4.62-0.356-0.3-0.972-0.943-1.516-1.511-0.483-0.504-0.924-0.961-1.151-1.153-0.284-0.24-0.704-0.204-0.94 0.079-0.237 0.281-0.203 0.703 0.079 0.94 0.207 0.175 0.607 0.597 1.048 1.057 0.595 0.621 1.209 1.264 1.623 1.611 2.483 2.079 5.467 4.323 6.061 4.713 0.491 0.323 1.548 0.776 2.367 0.776 0.657 0 1.163-0.151 1.513-0.445 0.469 0.183 1.003 0.184 1.516-0.016 0.607-0.235 1.105-0.708 1.388-1.281 0.525 0.112 1.127 0.033 1.673-0.241 0.535-0.269 0.921-0.681 1.113-1.163 0.531 0.028 1.077-0.16 1.529-0.548 0.765-0.655 0.976-1.673 0.533-2.592z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M13.333 8.666h-6c-0.368 0-0.667 0.299-0.667 0.667s0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h6c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667s-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M27.22 18.294c-0.207-0.305-0.62-0.389-0.925-0.181l-1.949 1.309c-0.305 0.205-0.387 0.62-0.181 0.925 0.129 0.191 0.34 0.295 0.555 0.295 0.127 0 0.256-0.036 0.371-0.113l1.949-1.309c0.305-0.205 0.387-0.62 0.181-0.925z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M23.081 21.476c-0.477-0.376-2.612-2.561-3.932-3.937-0.255-0.267-0.677-0.276-0.943-0.020-0.267 0.255-0.275 0.677-0.020 0.943 0.343 0.357 3.365 3.508 4.068 4.063 0.121 0.096 0.268 0.143 0.412 0.143 0.196 0 0.392-0.088 0.525-0.255 0.228-0.288 0.179-0.708-0.111-0.936z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M20.417 22.813c-0.799-0.639-2.805-2.771-3.259-3.264-0.251-0.272-0.671-0.288-0.943-0.040-0.271 0.249-0.289 0.672-0.040 0.943 0.024 0.025 2.419 2.611 3.408 3.403 0.123 0.097 0.271 0.145 0.416 0.145 0.195 0 0.389-0.087 0.521-0.249 0.229-0.288 0.183-0.708-0.104-0.937z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M17.764 24.156c-0.951-0.801-2.896-2.872-3.276-3.279-0.252-0.269-0.675-0.284-0.943-0.032-0.269 0.252-0.283 0.673-0.032 0.943 0.547 0.585 2.408 2.559 3.391 3.388 0.125 0.105 0.277 0.157 0.429 0.157 0.189 0 0.379-0.081 0.511-0.237 0.237-0.283 0.201-0.703-0.080-0.94z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M7.792 7.516c-1.143-1.083-5.712-1.433-7.085-1.515-0.189-0.009-0.364 0.053-0.497 0.18-0.133 0.125-0.209 0.301-0.209 0.485v12c0 0.368 0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h4c0.288 0 0.544-0.185 0.633-0.46 0.097-0.299 2.395-7.349 2.697-10.816 0.017-0.203-0.057-0.403-0.205-0.541zM4.18 18h-2.847v-10.619c2.143 0.169 4.455 0.537 5.295 0.945-0.353 2.92-1.952 8.108-2.448 9.673z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M31.333 7.333c-5.235 0-8.139 1.34-8.26 1.396-0.173 0.081-0.303 0.232-0.356 0.415s-0.027 0.379 0.073 0.541c0.824 1.327 3.404 8.695 3.9 10.492 0.080 0.289 0.343 0.489 0.643 0.489h4c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667v-12c0-0.369-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667zM30.667 19.333h-2.835c-0.632-2.059-2.499-7.427-3.54-9.645 1.017-0.345 3.203-0.939 6.375-1.013v10.659z"></path>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap the handshake in a symbol and give the symbol a viewBox attribute. Next you use the symbol and give the `use` element the position (x,y) and size (width, height) you need.

```
<use xlink:href="#handshake" x=".5" y=".5" width="90" height="90" />
```

In order to know the value for the viewBox I've wrapped first the handshake in a `g` element and I've used the `getBBox()` method.

```html
<svg class="c-section-heading__icon svg-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="91" height="91" viewBox="0 0 91 91" >
    <rect class="svg-icon__border" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="90" height="90" fill="gold"/> 

  <symbol id="handshake" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M25.267 19.713c-0.628-1.309-2.875-3.127-5.045-4.883-1.211-0.979-2.355-1.904-3.084-2.633-0.183-0.184-0.456-0.243-0.697-0.156-0.449 0.163-0.727 0.288-0.945 0.385-0.333 0.149-0.445 0.2-0.895 0.245-0.199 0.020-0.377 0.127-0.488 0.292-0.943 1.409-1.919 1.289-2.571 1.071-0.208-0.069-0.245-0.159-0.265-0.244-0.14-0.585 0.563-1.948 1.473-2.859 2.167-2.168 3.284-2.711 5.644-1.656 2.677 1.197 5.36 2.135 5.387 2.144 0.351 0.121 0.728-0.063 0.849-0.411 0.12-0.348-0.063-0.728-0.411-0.849-0.027-0.009-2.656-0.928-5.28-2.103-3.057-1.367-4.735-0.467-7.131 1.931-0.912 0.912-2.151 2.757-1.831 4.111 0.137 0.576 0.543 1.003 1.145 1.201 1.511 0.499 2.889 0.021 3.916-1.341 0.424-0.065 0.655-0.161 1.001-0.317 0.125-0.056 0.272-0.121 0.467-0.2 0.763 0.716 1.792 1.549 2.876 2.425 1.96 1.585 4.183 3.383 4.683 4.423 0.247 0.513-0.019 0.848-0.199 1.001-0.264 0.227-0.625 0.299-0.821 0.161-0.216-0.148-0.497-0.157-0.72-0.024-0.224 0.133-0.349 0.385-0.321 0.644 0.045 0.424-0.343 0.667-0.511 0.751-0.427 0.216-0.872 0.179-1.039 0.024-0.187-0.173-0.455-0.224-0.692-0.136-0.237 0.089-0.403 0.308-0.427 0.561-0.040 0.437-0.364 0.857-0.787 1.021-0.204 0.077-0.5 0.124-0.765-0.119-0.165-0.149-0.395-0.207-0.609-0.155-0.217 0.053-0.392 0.211-0.468 0.42-0.025 0.067-0.083 0.227-0.707 0.227-0.444 0-1.243-0.3-1.633-0.559-0.468-0.308-3.403-2.497-5.937-4.62-0.356-0.3-0.972-0.943-1.516-1.511-0.483-0.504-0.924-0.961-1.151-1.153-0.284-0.24-0.704-0.204-0.94 0.079-0.237 0.281-0.203 0.703 0.079 0.94 0.207 0.175 0.607 0.597 1.048 1.057 0.595 0.621 1.209 1.264 1.623 1.611 2.483 2.079 5.467 4.323 6.061 4.713 0.491 0.323 1.548 0.776 2.367 0.776 0.657 0 1.163-0.151 1.513-0.445 0.469 0.183 1.003 0.184 1.516-0.016 0.607-0.235 1.105-0.708 1.388-1.281 0.525 0.112 1.127 0.033 1.673-0.241 0.535-0.269 0.921-0.681 1.113-1.163 0.531 0.028 1.077-0.16 1.529-0.548 0.765-0.655 0.976-1.673 0.533-2.592z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M13.333 8.666h-6c-0.368 0-0.667 0.299-0.667 0.667s0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h6c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667s-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M27.22 18.294c-0.207-0.305-0.62-0.389-0.925-0.181l-1.949 1.309c-0.305 0.205-0.387 0.62-0.181 0.925 0.129 0.191 0.34 0.295 0.555 0.295 0.127 0 0.256-0.036 0.371-0.113l1.949-1.309c0.305-0.205 0.387-0.62 0.181-0.925z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M23.081 21.476c-0.477-0.376-2.612-2.561-3.932-3.937-0.255-0.267-0.677-0.276-0.943-0.020-0.267 0.255-0.275 0.677-0.020 0.943 0.343 0.357 3.365 3.508 4.068 4.063 0.121 0.096 0.268 0.143 0.412 0.143 0.196 0 0.392-0.088 0.525-0.255 0.228-0.288 0.179-0.708-0.111-0.936z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M20.417 22.813c-0.799-0.639-2.805-2.771-3.259-3.264-0.251-0.272-0.671-0.288-0.943-0.040-0.271 0.249-0.289 0.672-0.040 0.943 0.024 0.025 2.419 2.611 3.408 3.403 0.123 0.097 0.271 0.145 0.416 0.145 0.195 0 0.389-0.087 0.521-0.249 0.229-0.288 0.183-0.708-0.104-0.937z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M17.764 24.156c-0.951-0.801-2.896-2.872-3.276-3.279-0.252-0.269-0.675-0.284-0.943-0.032-0.269 0.252-0.283 0.673-0.032 0.943 0.547 0.585 2.408 2.559 3.391 3.388 0.125 0.105 0.277 0.157 0.429 0.157 0.189 0 0.379-0.081 0.511-0.237 0.237-0.283 0.201-0.703-0.080-0.94z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M7.792 7.516c-1.143-1.083-5.712-1.433-7.085-1.515-0.189-0.009-0.364 0.053-0.497 0.18-0.133 0.125-0.209 0.301-0.209 0.485v12c0 0.368 0.299 0.667 0.667 0.667h4c0.288 0 0.544-0.185 0.633-0.46 0.097-0.299 2.395-7.349 2.697-10.816 0.017-0.203-0.057-0.403-0.205-0.541zM4.18 18h-2.847v-10.619c2.143 0.169 4.455 0.537 5.295 0.945-0.353 2.92-1.952 8.108-2.448 9.673z"></path>
    <path class="svg-icon__item" d="M31.333 7.333c-5.235 0-8.139 1.34-8.26 1.396-0.173 0.081-0.303 0.232-0.356 0.415s-0.027 0.379 0.073 0.541c0.824 1.327 3.404 8.695 3.9 10.492 0.080 0.289 0.343 0.489 0.643 0.489h4c0.368 0 0.667-0.299 0.667-0.667v-12c0-0.369-0.299-0.667-0.667-0.667zM30.667 19.333h-2.835c-0.632-2.059-2.499-7.427-3.54-9.645 1.017-0.345 3.203-0.939 6.375-1.013v10.659z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#handshake" x=".5" y=".5" width="90" height="90" />
  </svg>
```